# Include search in jekyll site with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jekyll

I am trying to implement search in jekyll using angularjs but not able to display . can anyone suggest me how can i plan for search in jekyll site using angularjs.

on submit of search text need to shoe list of blog posts with search text. how can i form search.json and how  can add filter to load page faster .

another problem is can we use same index.html which is for blog

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
    <div class="entry">
      {% include blog/post_header.html post=post %}
      <div>
        {{ post.excerpt | markdownify }}
        <p><a href="{{ post.url }}">Read post <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

to again display filtered blogs ?

Comment: I can't understand what you really want, can you compress your problem in just 1 question?

Comment: I want guidance for implementing search in jekyll blog posts using angularjs

Comment: angularJS wont help you do search. You'll need to put your jekyll posts into a database like mongodb or postgres with `full text search` features. Then you could have an angularJS widget produce queries to the db. good luck.

Comment: Not angular, but I did add search to my GitHub hosted Jekyll blog using Azure Search and Azure functions. I blogged about it here https://hutchcodes.net/2016/12/azure-search-for-jekyll/